# Does Azure App Service gets unloaded if it makes HTTP Request every 1 minute?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, hangfire

i'm having a weird bug an i suspect that the `Always On` could be the key to resolve the problem here.
According to the document here [image]

The app will get unloaded if there's no coming traffic to it. Does it also get unloaded when i have a Hangfire background service attached to my service which perform a HTTP request to another service every 1 minute? I can't find it anywhere in the document since it states `no incoming traffic` and doesn't mention anything about `outcoming traffic`.

One more question, do i need to restart my Azure App Service to apply the configuration when switching the `Always On` from `off` to `on`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Always On` should be set in order to work. You have it also mentioned in the documentation https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html

Comment: Do i also have to restart my Azure application in order to apply the configuration?